# Does this pushback to a shared pointers vector causes memory leaks?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I'm making a node editor for a project I'm in, and I have an std::vector of shared pointers of `Node`, a class which has derived classes of different node types.

As I say, this is a vector of shared pointers (I'm experimenting with smart pointers so in this I'm a bit newbie), and when I create a node, the next code is executed:

```
 DerivedNodeClass* d_node = new DerivedNodeClass();
 nodes.push_back(std::make_shared<Node>((Node*)d_node);
```

So this is working fine, but I was wondering if that way of creating nodes caused a memory leak or something similar, because I'm not sure if this is a "proper way" of creating classes and adding them into a vector of smart pointers.

After I stop using nodes, I just iterate the vector calling `.reset()`, but still, I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

Note that any of the derived classes of `Node` handles any pointer or nothing related to dynamic memory.

Comment: creating something does not cause the leak but not deleting it does. Hence, one cannot know if your code is leak free by only looking at the construction. Smart pointers help a lot, but even with smart pointers it is possible to get it wrong. Why do you think your code would cause a leak?

Comment: Unrelated but... the `(Node *)` cast shouldn't be required .  If it is then there's something suspicious going on.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::make_shared`? `auto d_node = std::make_shared<DerivedNodeClass>(); nodes.push_back(std::move(d_node));`.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 yes, right, sorry, upon deletion all the nodes are iterated and `node[i].reset()` is called, I'll edit the question.

Comment: @Evg in fact, I use `make_shared`, but I have it templated with different options so when I copied it from the code I copied the wrong line, I'll also modify it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might know, shared pointers delete data they point at by themselves at the moment the last shared pointer stops to point at the data (last reference is destroyed - shared pointers keep information about how many shared pointers point to this data stored in memory).

The only way you might have a problem with memory leaks while using shared pointers is when you have for example `class Wrapper` as a container for instances of `class Node` where each Node that is stored in the container in class Wrapper has a reference (as shared_ptr) to the Wrapper class and from somewhere else there is a shared_ptr pointing to the instance of Wrapper class (from the place where the instance was created before). This means the instance of Wrapper class is pointing to the instance of Node class and at the same time instance of Node class is pointing to instance of Wrapper class and there is another pointer to the instance of Wrapper class. (I tried to make a sketch for it here:
[before destruction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlJFe.png),
[after destruction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwXeG.png), it helped me to understand smart pointers)

When you try to call destructor for Wrapper class it deletes the shared_ptr from the place of creation, but each of Node instances in the container points to the Wrapper instance. There still exists shared_ptr to the instance of Wrapper class you are just trying to destruct. That means there is a reference in shared_ptr to this Wrapper class instance **and therefore** destruction of this instance will cause a memory leak.

If you want to fix this problem, you should check weak pointers (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr).
Hope I helped.

Comment: Wow thanks for the explanation and the sketches, it helped me a lot! According to what you say, then I should not have memory leaks from here then. Thanks you :)

Comment: I would prefer to call constructor right into the make_shared, but this should be fine too.